# Making list from elements from each level of a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list:

```
cleaner = [['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777']]
```

I want to check if another list contains same value, I write:

```
any('31_300323' in sl for sl in cleaner)
```

,
and get "True", but if I write:

```
suka = []
for h in cleaner:
    if any(h in sl for sl in cleaner):
        suka.append(h)
```

the emptry list remains empty. Why? Thank You

Comment: what you want in suka list ?

Comment: show your desired output.!! also i think maybe you wanted to do `if any(h==sl for sl in cleaner):` this will output suka as `[['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777']]`

Comment: for example, the other list zajavki = ['21_220223', '21_110123', '23_200123', '26_100822', '25_260123', '31_300323']. I want to append to suka all co-incidences with any level of cleaner.

Comment: is your cleaner is `nested_list`?@LevdarArmenia

Comment: yes, "cleaner" is nested

Comment: can you provide an example by taking any testcase and what will be it's desired output.. write now.. it is not clear to me @LevdarArmenia

Comment: zajavki = ['21_220223', '21_110123', '23_200123', '26_100822', '25_260123', '31_300323']  cleaner =[['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777']]. Want to append '31_300323' to suka list, because it is both in nested cleaner and zajavki

Comment: now I understood one way is to flatten the cleaner list and than check for every item in cleaner.. see the answer for better understanding @LevdarArmenia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**flatten function:** used to flatten the `nested_list`

**Code:**

```
def flatten(lst):
    """Flattens a nested list of any depth."""
    flattened = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            flattened.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            flattened.append(item)
    return flattened

cleaner=[['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777','21_110123'],[[['26_100822']]]]
zajavki=['21_220223', '21_110123', '23_200123', '26_100822', '25_260123', '31_300323']

# Flatten the nested list
cleaner_flat = flatten(cleaner)
suko=[]
for word in cleaner_flat:
    if word in zajavki:
        suko.append(word)
print(suko) # ['31_300323','21_110123','26_100822']
```

**Note*** If you don't want duplicates you can use data structure `set()`

Let's say you known the depth of the `nested_list` than you don't need to `flatten` the nested list

**Code:**

```
cleaner=[['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777'],['Ze:', '23_200123', 'RE778'],['De:', '21_220223', 'RE779']]
zajavki=['21_220223', '21_110123', '23_200123', '26_100822', '25_260123', '31_300323']

suko=[]

for sublist in cleaner:
    for check in sublist:
        if check in zajavki:
            suko.append(check)
print(suko) #['31_300323', '23_200123', '21_220223']
```

Comment: many thanks. Would there be an option without flattening? cleaner =[['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777']] has element RE777. Eventually I want to populate a dictionary with pairs of 31_300323 - RE777, if 31_300323  is in the other list. THus, I need to keep structure of the nested list.

Comment: Is `nested_list` level is specific? If the depth of every sublists are same and know the depth than we don't need flattening list.. @LevdarArmenia

Answer (score 0):

Let's iterate your code,
when you write "for h in cleaner" it means that h is every element in cleaner so the first and only element in cleaner is ['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777'] so now h would be the list i mentioned.
Now let us see your if condition in this condition you are checking if h in sl where sl is ['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777'] by the same logic in above paragraph since sl doesn't have ['Re:', '31_300323', 'RE777'] as its element therefore it would return false and therefore your list is empty.
You are welcome

Comment: many thanks, how should I iterate for any element of the cleaner?